# Execute only once in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So in my game I have a class called `MovementService`. This class handles moving an object when the uses presses an arrow key. However, when you press the up arrow 5 times in a row real quick, the object will move one square 5 times. This feels weird, because you're already done with pressing, but the character is still moving.

So I went and added some code to the class to try and prevent that. But now the movement is only executed once. But thing is, it's the first movement. How can I make sure it's the last press?

```
class MovementService():
    lastExecutionEpoch = 0
    minimumDifference = 1

    def moveUp(self):
        self.execute('MOVEUP')

    def moveDown(self):
        self.execute('MOVEDOWN')

    def execute(self, movement):
        if self.lastExecutionEpoch < (int(time.time()) - self.minimumDifference):
            self.lastExecutionEpoch = int(time.time())
            ...
            Do the actual movement
            ...
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is called debouncing. In any case, for that to work you'll have to pause the execution until the user stops pressing. Wouldn't the first press be a better indicator of the user's action?

Comment: You could have a variable which resets every second to False. If you press the key you set it to True. Then use a condition to only move when var = True.